# Ansible EC2_tag_environment_production

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am looking up how to differentiate between Production and Stage environments with Ansible. I have came across [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#how-to-differentiate-staging-vs-production) documentation.

I am under the impression that Ansible has a build in variable similar to `ansible.hostname` labelled `ec2_tag_environment_production`. However, when I try to add it to my playbook, it errors out! I am fine with it erroring out ( I can fix it ) but what I am seeing is that it errors out in the wrong playbook. For example, if I run an playbook aimed at a stage server, it attempts to run the production playbook. Here is what my main playbook consists of:

```
   ---
   - name: Running Production Playbook
     include: production.yml
     when: ec2_tag_environment_production = 'production'

   - name: Running Stage playbook
     include: stage.yml
     when: ec2_tag_environment_production = 'staging'
```

I have added the environment:staging|production as a tag in AWS. Can someone let me know what needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 dynamic inventory script for Ansible populate facts for EC2 hosts. If a host is marked with tag `environment`, then fact `ec2_tag_environment` will be available for that instance and this fact's value is the value of tag in EC2.

So in your case:

```
---
- name: Running Production Playbook
  include: production.yml
  when: ec2_tag_environment == 'production'

- name: Running Stage playbook
  include: stage.yml
  when: ec2_tag_environment == 'staging'
```

But you can also use dynamic include:

```
- include: "{{ ec2_tag_environment }}.yml"
```

Comment: This looks promising. Except, I keep getting hit with errors that ec2_tag_environment is undefined. Is there any other thing I should add in the yml file provided to get ansible to recognize the variable?

Comment: Are you sure you make use of [ec2.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) dynamic inventory script (like `ansible-playbook -i ec2.py myplaybook.yml`)?

Comment: Ok, now i see what you mean. Thanks for providing the link to ec2.py. I will try to follow instructions on adding it to Ansible